# jquery auto refresh not working?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Here is a script I wrote so i could refresh a div with content every 5 seconds but for some reason it doesnt work ... I wanted it to load it with the page then start the refresh I didn't want it to have to wait for the refresh to show up.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
function page_load(){
    $('#contentforads').load('<?php print $actual_link ?>/ads.php').fadeIn("slow");
}
function refresh(){
    page_load();
    var auto_refresh = setInterval(page_load,5000);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`page_load()` doesn't return a function, therefore you should pass it by reference to the interval rather than executing it.

```
var auto_refresh = setInterval(page_load,5000);
```

Don't forget to execute `refresh` to begin the interval.

```
function page_load(){
    $('#contentforads').load('<?php print $actual_link ?>/ads.php').fadeIn("slow");
}
function refresh(){
    page_load();
    var auto_refresh = setInterval(page_load,5000);
}
refresh();
```

Comment: nothing is in the console and here is the link that it is generating http://alpha.quickdailylaugh.com/ads.php

Comment: I take it that url is something internal to your network? i get dns errors when i hit it with fiddler

Comment: yes this is a local site that i just added to my hosts file

Comment: nah, i trust that it's just plain text. was just going to double check

Comment: what do you mean by executing it ?

Comment: `refresh()`, for example, `<body onload="refresh()">`

Comment: no i thought just having the function would refresh the div with content ?

Comment: Nope, all you did was define a function, you have to execute it at least once to make it start.

Comment: this works... but it still takes 5 seconds for it to even show is there a way to get it to show on page load and then do the interval ?
function page_load(){
    $('#contentforads').load('<?php print $actual_link ?>/ads.php').fadeIn("slow");
}
function refresh(){
    page_load();
    var auto_refresh = setInterval(page_load,5000);
}
refresh();

Comment: it should be refreshing immediately, and then 5 seconds later.

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
setInterval(page_load(),5000);
```

to:

```
setInterval(page_load,5000);
```

Comment: I changed it and still nothing loads ?

Answer (score 0):

I'd change your code to this:

```
var a = function page_load(){
  $('#contentforads').append(new Date());
}

setInterval(a, 5000); //every 5 seconds
```

Heres why I recommend:

- Less code xD
- Functions take up memory as they are considered variables in JS so this is more optimized

Note: Working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PjS3N/5/)

Comment: Sorry, I messed up. You were closer than me. XD. I changed the code and got a working fiddle (sorry I stripped some of your original work).